# How do I get a list of referrers and referrers of referrers

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table member2. `referrer_id` is the id of the member that referred the member. The `main_referrer_id` is the id of the member that referred the `referrer_id`. I would like to get a list of all the members who referred 3 members and a list of members who referred 3 referrers.
That is `referrer_id` brought 3 members and `main_referrer_id` brought 3 `referrer_id`

```
CREATE TABLE `member2` (
`id` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
`referrer_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`main_referrer_id` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
`first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`surname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`completed_level1` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`current_level` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`status` varchar(2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `member2`
--

INSERT INTO `member2` (`id`, `referrer_id`, `main_referrer_id`, 
`first_name`, `surname`, `completed_level1`, `current_level`, `status`) VALUES
('100001', '0', NULL, 'Moses', 'Ali', '1', '4', '1'),
('100002', '100001', NULL, 'jj', 'jj', '1', '1', '1'),
('100003', '100001', NULL, 'jj', 'jj', '0', '1', '1'),
('100004', '100001', NULL, 'jj', 'jj', '0', '1', '1'),
('100005', '100002', '100001', 'jj', 'jj', '0', '1', '1'),
('100006', '100002', '100001', 'jj', 'jj', '0', '1', '1'),
('100007', '100002', '100001', 'jj', 'jj', '0', '1', '1'),
('100008', '100005', '100002', 'Dad', 'Adli', '0', '1', '0'),
('100009', '100005', '100002', 'Dad', 'Adli', '0', '1', '0'),
('100010', '100005', '100002', 'Dad', 'Adli', '0', '1', '0');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `member2`
--
ALTER TABLE `member2`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

This is the query I wrote but not working the way it should.

```
select distinct referrer_id from member where referrer_id != '0' 
AND main_referrer_id is null
```

Comment: "The main_referrer_id is the id of the member that referred the referrer_id". This doesn't seem like a good data structure, or even to be necessary. Surely the "member that referred the referrer_id" should be stored in the "referrer_id" column for that member's record? i.e. if when member id = 3, the referrer_id = 2, then I can find the id of member 2's referrer by looking in referrer_id where id = 2. Your suggested structure also has an in-built limitation where the id in main_referrer_id then has no way of itself being referred by someone else. So your hierarchy can't go more than 3 levels.

Comment: @ADyson A registered member is required to refer 3 members to complete level 1. Each of the 3 members in expected to refer members each. If any of the three have not referred anyone and the upline refers additional members, these additional members will be downlines to any of his first members that he referred but it will recorded that he is the one that referred them. That is where the main referrer comes in